# XML File Load Issue in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was develop a small app using Unity3D.In this app i was displays text. This app Text load  was works in systems but nor works in devices.This text gets using .xml file. This xml file locates in **Resources** folder. Please find the following code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;

public class InsultGenerator : MonoBehaviour {

    public UILabel msg;
    int indexNo = 0;
    bool isFlag = false;

    //TODO :: For usage of XML
    XmlDocument xml;
    public XmlNodeList xmllist;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        Debug.Log ("InsultGenerator :: :: Start() ");
        indexNo = IGUtils.getIndexNo();
        Debug.Log ("indexNo :: " + indexNo);
        xml = new XmlDocument ();
        xml.Load (Application.dataPath + "/Resources/I.xml");
        xmllist = xml.SelectNodes ("insults/record");
        Debug.Log ("XML Toatal Records : " + xmllist.Count);
        IBtn ();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
    //TODO :: IBtn Click Code
    public void IBtn()
    {
        Debug.Log ("I Btn Clicked  ");

        if (indexNo == xmllist.Count) {
            indexNo = 0;
            Debug.Log ("****  indexNO **** :: " +indexNo);
            IGUtils.setIndexNo(indexNo);
        }
        isFlag = true;
        for (int index = indexNo; index < xmllist.Count; index++)
        {
            if(isFlag)
             {
                indexNo = indexNo + 1;
                XmlNode node=xmllist[index].SelectSingleNode("level1");
                Debug.Log("Node Data = " +node.InnerText);
                int nodeINT = int.Parse(node.InnerText);

                if(nodeINT == 1)
                    {
                        isFlag = false;

                         Debug.Log("Node Data = " +node.InnerText);
                         XmlNode nodeString=xmllist[index].SelectSingleNode("english");
                         Debug.Log("nodeString.InnerText :: "+nodeString.InnerText);
                         msg.text = nodeString.InnerText;//here text assign to label.
                         IGUtils.setIndexNo(indexNo);
                         break;
                     }
               }
         }

    }

}
```

When ever clicks button ,It goes button click event IGBtn() but not load text .I hope to its problem with getting text from xml.Can you please solve the above problem.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

`IBtn ()` is called from `Start()`.

There is nothing that is triggered by a click.

Perhaps replace:

```
public void IBtn()
```

with:

```
void OnMouseDown()
```

And then add a Collider component (such as BoxCollider) to the GameObject with `isTrigger = true`, so it can be clicked.

Comment: Problem with Xml not button click event.@Qubei